# Why does my Windows 7 boot up to a black screen after login?

Tags: windows-7

I get a black screen after I login, with a window of Windows explorer open. I have to manually ctrl+alt+del->Task manager->Run and run explorer.exe before desktop shows up.

How can I remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about cause, but fact that you have a Windows Explorer window opened then is showing that it tried to start explorer.exe by itself, but for some reason resolved to open only this and not the whole desktop (same behaviour as running again explorer.exe when the desktop is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely explanation is a virus infection that either failed to or succeeded in taking over your boot process. The possible solutions are in order: (1) antivirus scans, (2) system repair, (3) total reinstall.

Make first sure that all your data is backed up.

Load and install some antiviruses, make sure they are up to date, and scan deeply your hard disk. I recommend using at least [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php). I also like Avast.

If that doesn't work for any reason, you may use a rescue live-CD virus scanner : I like best [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira%5Fantivir%5Frescue%5Fsystem.html) because it gets updated several times a day and so the download CD is up-to-date. As a boot CD it's autonomous and doesn't work using your Windows system.

If no virus is found, use "sfc /scannow" to repair important Windows files.
See this [article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/sfc-scannow.htm).

If that also doesn't work, you should [Perform a Repair Installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

If nothing works, you should format the hard disk and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Try the answer of Redandwhite before you do mine. The antivirus scans wouldn't hurt, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but the black screen would go away after  a couple of minutes, and I would be logged in normally. It only happened with my user account, so I'm guessing that my user profile got screwed up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on my laptop, except it just stayed at the black screen.  I could still boot fine in safe mode, but  normal mode would just go black.  Eventually I figured out that while win7 had identified the correct video card, it installed the wrong driver.  After manually updating the video card driver, my non-boot black screen never happened again. (Though it's not perfect as sometimes when it has gone to powersaving mode and shut the screen off it won't come back up, but this is rare)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've had the same issue. I have Geforce 250GTS, apparently other people with NVidia cards are experiencing the same.

Just downloading and installing a newer driver for it solved the issue and windows now works fine.